# How to determine current CPU usage on Linux, preferably using C++?

Tags: c++, linux, cpu-usage

I have tried using this program (adapted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64166/1876983)):

```
// First segment (down to L49) is from SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/26930298/1876983
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

using namespace std;

static unsigned long long lastTotalUser, lastTotalUserLow, lastTotalSys, lastTotalIdle;

void init(){
    FILE* file = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
    fscanf(file, "cpu %llu %llu %llu %llu", &lastTotalUser, &lastTotalUserLow,
        &lastTotalSys, &lastTotalIdle);
    fclose(file);
}

double getCurrentValue(){
    double percent;
    FILE* file;
    unsigned long long totalUser, totalUserLow, totalSys, totalIdle, total;

    file = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
    fscanf(file, "cpu %llu %llu %llu %llu", &totalUser, &totalUserLow,
        &totalSys, &totalIdle);
    fclose(file);

    if (totalUser < lastTotalUser || totalUserLow < lastTotalUserLow ||
        totalSys < lastTotalSys || totalIdle < lastTotalIdle){
        //Overflow detection. Just skip this value.
        percent = -1.0;
    }
    else{
        total = (totalUser - lastTotalUser) + (totalUserLow - lastTotalUserLow) +
            (totalSys - lastTotalSys);
        percent = total;
        total += (totalIdle - lastTotalIdle);
        percent /= total;
        percent *= 100;
    }

    lastTotalUser = totalUser;
    lastTotalUserLow = totalUserLow;
    lastTotalSys = totalSys;
    lastTotalIdle = totalIdle;

    return percent;
}

int main() {
    double CPU = getCurrentValue();
    printf("%.2f", CPU);

    return 0;
}
```

To determine *current* total CPU usage on Linux, but it seems to be determining *average* total CPU usage. At the moment the KDE CPU monitor is telling me my CPU usage is just 17% and this program tells me it is 60.19%. Now earlier today I was compiling a heap of software using the Portage package manager so the 60.19% seems to be more accurately represent my *average* CPU usage since I turned this PC on. This CPU usage figure has been going down since I stopped compiling software, further supporting the idea this is the *average* CPU usage, not the *current* CPU usage.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1332955/42610

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use [exec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)) function in C++ to execute any relevant Linux command to get these values. You can execute Linux commands like `top` or `uptime` with `>` operator.
For example: `uptime > output.txt` and then can later read `output.txt` file.

Comment: And what command would I use to determine CPU usage? If you don't tell me that I can't see how you can expect me to accept this answer.

Comment: That is quite possible right?. One way could be to use `mpstat | awk '$3 ~ /CPU/ { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i ~ /%idle/) field=i } } $3 ~ /all/ { print 100 - $field }'` . Or you can refer to this link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux

Comment: That command returns nothing for me; while `grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage "%"}'` and `top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | \
           sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | \
           awk '{print 100 - $1"%"}'` both give ~58% which is now what the C++ program is telling me, making them seem like average CPU usage.

Comment: I just gave you a possible way to use several different things. If you know how to get cpu utilization using some other way like python etc. then you can execute that from c++ and store its output in a file and then can read it.

Comment: @BrentonHorne Was it helpful?