# Command line argument to int in less then 3 LOC?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

At [How to convert a command-line argument to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797813/how-to-convert-a-command-line-argument-to-int) it is shown how to assing a comand line argument to an int.

I'm looking for short way. Not using `atoi()`.

```
int size;
istringstream s(argv[1]);
s >> size;
```

With all the cool C++11/14/17 I still need 3 LOC for that? Or is there a `int size = magic(argv[1])` around?

Comment: Your answer is already provided on your linked question `int val = stoi(argv[1]);`

Comment: The linked question has a C / C++98 answer. C++11 way is similar, but technically different.

Comment: @lisyarus there are few things that are legal C++98, and *differently behaving* in C++11. This is not one of them

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes but its not the accepted answer there (because this question is different, it asks for an alternative to `atoi`, shorter then 3LOC).

Comment: @KcFnMi That doesn't really matter.  The accepted answer is just the answer the OP found most helpful. It doesn't mean it the "the answer" to the question.

Comment: I did ask the answerer if they would add it so it could be in the top position.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [`std::atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi):

```
int size = std::atoi(argv[1]);
```

Beware that it provides awful error reporting - it just returns `0` is no conversion can be performed. A better alternative is [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), which accepts an `std::string` and throws an exception on error:

```
int size = std::stoi(argv[1]); // note implicit conversion from const char * to std::string
```

Comment: Will I be wrong if I say this `atoi` is not C++?

Comment: @KcFnMi - Looks C++ enough to me. It is declared in a C++ standard library header, and is in namespace `std`.

Comment: @KcFnMi I suppose you will, indeed. What makes you say this?

Comment: @KcFnMi It is a C function that was brought into the C++ standard.  So, technically, it is a C++ function but it does have a C interface.

Comment: @KcFnMi I think you are mistaking it for `itoa` which is indeed not standard.

Comment: @lisyarus it comes from `C` `stdlib.h` which in `C++` is provided by `cstdlib`. And some say you should not use `atoi` anymore. But if u guys say `atoi` is the only 1LOC way to do it, even nowadasys, thenI'll accept this as the answer

Comment: @KcFnMi `atoi` is a `C` function from `<stdlib.h>`. `std::atoi` is a `C++` function from `<cstdlib>`. They are indeed the same underneath, but `std::atoi` is still a standard `C++` function.

Comment: It is important to note that `std::stoi` only throws if it can't parse any of the string into a number, `std::stoi("1zzzz")` will not throw and return 1, you need to use the optional pos parameter if you want to ensure the whole string was parsed successfully.